# Rotating an image in OneNote 2010

Tags: microsoft-onenote-2010

I scanned a brochure to PDF.  It was portrait & should be landscape so I rotated the page in Acrobat and saved the PDF.  I sent it to OneNote 2010 using the "printer", and it shows up in portrait mode in my OneNote file.  I cannot find anyway to rotate the picture within OneNote 2010.

I did find a link to an image rotator add-in for OneNote 2007, which installed for me but does not actually rotate the image.

Has anyone solved this problem?

Comment: Have you tried to uncheck the "Auto-Rotate and Center" Option in the printer while sending it to OneNote?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

MaoPU's helped tremendously for me. The main shift in thinking I needed was to view the OneNote printer as exactly that - a printer that can have modified settings.

The PDF I had was a PPT that showed in Acrobat Reader in landscape, but it printed into OneNote as portrait when I dragged and dropped the doc into OneNote.

Instead of dragging and dropping the file into OneNote, I printed to the OneNote printer (File -> Print) in Acrobat Reader and deselected the option to auto-rotate and center OR select Landscape in the printer properties to make the document show up in OneNote as you desire.

Answer (score 0):

PDF Print out rotation (greyed out) work around.

1. Open Onenote and Microsoft Word (I split my screen display).
2. Use Ctrl and A, to select the all the pdf print out in Onenote
3. Drag and drop the selection across onto a blank word document.
   (allow it to transfer a copy)
4. Use Ctrl A in word to select all,
5. Drag the selection back across to a new page in one note.
6. The Rotate option in Onenote Draw tab will now be available.
7. Individually select and rotate any pages necessary.

Answer (score -1):

Select the PDF file you want to print and under the print menu, click on the Page Setup and select the landscape orientation then click Ok to print.